# Embeds for Discord Python Bots

Tags: python, discord, bots

so i made this code where users can chose their own embed color, but if they out in a wrong embed, it will mess up the whole thing and they need to redo, is there anyway to make it so if they don't respond or put in a incorrect hex code it will automatically go to the hex color FF00EC.

```
@client.command(aliases=['say'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def embed(ctx):

    questions = ["Which should be the tile of the embed?",
            "What should be the description?",
            "What is the color of the embed? This should be a hex color. Note, Must put a `Correct` Hex color or you will need to redo this also leave out the #."]

    answers = []

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    for i in questions:
        await ctx.send(i)

        try:
            msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=30, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send('You did not answer in time. Please do it under 30 seconds next time.')
            return
        else:
            answers.append(msg.content)

    embedcolor = answers[2]

    embed = discord.Embed(description=answers[1], title=answers[0], colour=int(embedcolor, 16))

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

so here is my code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try except statement to do this easily.

```py
import re
@client.command(aliases=['say'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def embed(ctx):

    questions = ["Which should be the tile of the embed?",
            "What should be the description?",
            "What is the color of the embed? This should be a hex color. Note, Must put a `Correct` Hex color or you will need to redo this also leave out the #."]

    answers = []

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    for i in questions:
        await ctx.send(i)

        try:
            msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=30, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send('You did not answer in time. Please do it under 30 seconds next time.')
            return
        else:
            answers.append(msg.content)

    embedcolor = answers[2]

    embed = discord.Embed(description=answers[1], title=answers[0], colour=int(embedcolor, 16))
    if re.search(r'^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}$', embedcolor):
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(description=answers[1], title=answers[0], colour=int("FF00EC", 16))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Basically, if the color is invalid we set the color to FF00EC and send the message like that.

Comment: For some reason it is still not working for me

Comment: @Kepzix Be more specific, do you get any errors, does it set it to another color?

Comment: no errors, it just does not put in the embed, if u mess up

Comment: @Kepzix I edited my code, it should work now.

Comment: For some reason it does not work still, https://mid-evil-tk.glitch.me/invite, invite the bot and do r!say.